# Choose the best Client/Server Validation Framework for MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, frameworks

Im trying to choose the best server/client validation framework to use with my MVC application. I would like to know what is the best validation framework to use with MVC to do server/client validation.

My options are:

- Castle validator
- Microsoft Data Annotations
- nHibernate Validator

Comment: How can someone help you with this question when you have not even given your validation requirements? If you want the best framework for the problem then should should specify your requirements - how will you want to validate? do you want built in server/client validation functionality? will your validation rules be simple (length/type/required) or complex (multiple fields per condition / DDD aggregate tree invariant constraints / etc..)? With these specifics one can answer your question in a very un-subjective manner. Your question need not be tagged subjective if you make it more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using [**xVal**](http://xval.codeplex.com/) with great success.

The best thing is you can fully automate validation:

- put `DataAnnotations` (or special rules) to your business layer POCO classes (if you have them) or entity classes' metadata *buddy* classes if you use entities up to controller layer
- write an ActionFilter that will automatically validate parameters to your controller actions - it's best if all your POCOs (or entities) implement a certain interface that defines `Validate()` method, filter calls this method and fills `ModelState.Errors` when validation fails.
- Add `if (ModelState.IsValid) { ... }` in your controller action that needs to work differently when model isn't valid
- Put <%= Html.ValidationMessage(...) %> in your views that will display validation errors
- Add xVal's client validation to your views if desired

This way you've set up automatic object validation. All your controller actions will do is check Model validity.

Asp.net MVC 2 will have something very similar to xVal already built in the framework so it's up to you which version are you using.

Answer (score 2):

With the upcoming MVC 2, it looks like MS is leaning towards the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` library. It's pretty nice - does a lot of code generation for you.

Comment: thanks for you response, 
is it better compared to Castle which has been arround for a while now?

Comment: Castle seems to be more feature rich. This is geared towards ASP.NET Dynamic Data. I haven't used it though, so not sure.